# VBA: Finding a number inside a larger number with Instr

Tags: excel, vba

Our data exports at work have an annoying habit of comma separating distinct numeric identifiers, which excel interprets as a single long number.

To try and find if a specific number buried in there, I tried experimenting with the Instr function, but I encountered a problem.

```
Sub arrayTest()

arrTest = Array("11", "22", "33", "44")
arrTest2 = Array("1111", "1111", "1111", "1111")

For j = 0 To UBound(arrTest)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrTest2)
        If InStr(1, CStr(arrTest(j)), CStr(arrTest2(i))) > 0 Then Debug.Print j, i
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

This code produces nothing, but I'm not quite sure why!

Is there a way to use Instr in this way? My latest idea was to try using CStr to force the numbers to act as strings, even though they already are! But still it doesn't seem to want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip the INSTR inputs:

```
InStr(1, CStr(arrTest2(i)), CStr(arrTest(j)))
```

String to be searched is before the search string.

---

```
Sub arrayTest()

arrTest = Array("11", "22", "33", "44")
arrTest2 = Array("1111", "1111", "1111", "1111")

For j = 0 To UBound(arrTest)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrTest2)
        If InStr(1, CStr(arrTest2(i)), CStr(arrTest(j))) > 0 Then Debug.Print j, i
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

[image]